# Help creating ZIP files Windows won't block

Tags: php, windows, linux, encoding, zip

I've made an application that takes tagged versions of a project from an hg repository and creates a downloadable ZIP file of that the tagged revision.

The files are created on a MediaTemple server running Linux using CodeIgniter's ZIP Encoding Library. Everything works fine... on a Mac. But, when I download the files on a Windows computer, the archive is blocked from being extracted.

The ZIP contains `.html`, `.css`, `.gif`, `.png` and `.js` files, and I am pretty sure the `.js` files are the security culprit, but I am wondering why I can download the [Jcrop jQuery plugin](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Download.html) (or any other examples) as a ZIP file and extract it without Windows ever interfering, even though it obviously contains `.js` files, but something about my ZIP file is posing a security risk.

Normally I would just find a quick software workaround for my particular situation, but since the plan is to sell access to these files, a quick software fix or an FAQ doesn't seem very user-friendly.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if you need more info.

You can download an example file [here](http://manasto.info/so/download.zip).

**EDIT:**

- I am running Windows XP
- I am not running anti-virus
- The warning is: **Windows has blocked access to these files to help protect your computer**
- I've unblocked the file but that does nothing
- The file is on my desktop

**EDIT 2:**

- I added an example file at the bottom. Or you can see it [here](http://manasto.info/so/download.zip)
- I have only used default extraction tools on XP and Windows 7.
- The ZIP appears to be empty on Windows and I can't see or open any of the files.

**EDIT 3:**

- From the comments and answers, it appears that the file names were the problem due to an extra `/` being added somewhere in the process. I've uploaded an [new example download](http://manasto.info/so/fixed.zip) generated by my app with the file name fix, which you can download [here](http://manasto.info/so/fixed.zip). Please let me know if that fixes the problem.

Comment: You may need to right click the Zip File go to Properties and choose "Unblock." Depending on download/security settings on the machine, some downloaded files are "blocked" by default.

Comment: Can you upload an example zip file? Or tell us in what way they get blocked (anti-virus software such as Avast?)

Comment: I've done the 'Unblock' thing, but that doesn't matter. Windows just keeps telling me it's blocked. Also... I am not running any anti-virus software that doesn't come with Windows XP.

Comment: Does that happen even when you use an application (other than Windows) to extract the files? (Ie: 7-zip, WinRar, etc)

Comment: Can you not open the file _at all_ or can you not open it with a script?

Comment: **1:** I added an example file at the bottom. **2:** I have only used default extraction tools on XP and Windows 7. **3:** The ZIP appears to be empty on Windows and I can't see or open any of the files.

Comment: I've downloaded your example file and I think tamewhale is correct. I could open in winrar but not using the XP zip extraction tool. When I looked at the folders in Winrar I could see the folders were called \scripts etc. If you can get rid of that \ somehow you'll probably be all right.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for that... apparently that extra `/` in the file name doesn't show up on a Mac. I just ran some tests where I logged the file path I was zipping and noticed that there were some extra `/`s in there. Leave an answer below and I'll come back to it on Monday if it ends up solving the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, the leading '/' is what's causing the zip to not be allowed to be extracted.  I've proven this by writing a Python script to create a modified version of the zip file without the absolute file paths:

```
from zipfile import *

orig = ZipFile('download.zip', 'r')
fixed = ZipFile('fixed.zip', 'w')
for fileinfo in orig.infolist():
    fixed.writestr(fileinfo.filename[1:], orig.read(fileinfo.filename)) 
fixed.close()
```

(this doesn't re-compress the files, but it proves it's the file names that are causing the problem)

If you're using the CodeIgniter zip library's function `read_dir`, then that must be the culprit that's using absolute file paths.  Try recursively walking the directory structure using PHP instead and use the `add_data` function instead.  That allows you to use any arbitrary path structure for each file, so you can write relative paths.

Comment: I added a fixed example download... would you let me know if that fixes the problem. It should be easily extractable by a regular old user. I would, but I don't have access to a PC on the weekends :)

Answer (score 3):

This can happen when files are zipped using the full directory path rather than the relative path. You can find an example of this problem here:

http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/p/1416/4532.aspx#4532

You may have to use another zip utility or write your own.

Comment: I thought this might be the case. This is actually one of those things were it worked the first time, but the project was getting out of hand so I scrapped a lot of code. When I went back and looked I noticed that the way I was referencing the files was different the first time. I'll have to test it on Monday when I get ahold of a PC.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to mention which version of windows you are using as well as the exact error you're getting. Is it windows 7 and you're trying to open files in a protected folder by chance or are you just trying to open it on the desktop?

I don't think this has anything to do with the the way the zip file was made but I could be wrong.